# Can we use eclipse search plugin in our plugin? If yes, then how can we do this?

Tags: java, eclipse, search, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to develop a sample eclipse plugin which will be able to call eclipse search plugin. 
We want to call search plugin by passing certain text to search in whole workbench. And we want to call the plugin for a List so that we cant get the collective result.

I have gone through some plugin tutorials but couldnot find any fruitful idea...

Comment: Have a look at JDT search engine: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_search.htm